# Don't show hidden divs in wizard on page refresh?

Tags: jquery, css, html

I created custom wizard that uses hidden divs for wizard pages.
Here is the [demo](http://jsbin.com/eziju/) and the [source code](http://jsbin.com/eziju/edit).

You will notice that on each refresh (F5 or ctrl-r) of a browser, divs with input boxes will be shown for couple of (mili)seconds. Is there a way to eliminate this effect?

> This question is connected with [how-to-preserve-textbox-values-on-client-side-using-wizard-next-and-back-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947552/how-to-preserve-textbox-values-on-client-side-using-wizard-next-and-back-button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the CSS style for the ids that should initially be hidden to include "display:none;".  Then, the browser should only display the div when you've used JQuery's show() (or the equivalent).

Comment: But I already did that with this jquery code on document ready

// Hide all pages save the first. 
$("#wizardContainer").children(".wizardpage").hide(); 
$("#wizardContainer").children(".wizardpage:first").addClass("active").show();

Comment: This seems to happen only "onload" you should get them to be hidden in the first place. John seems to be right.

Answer (score 1):

Putting jquery aside, it seems that the code that hides the divs is happening onload.

Up until then, they show up. Like John Fisher has commented, set them to be hidden by default (either CSS or inline to `display:none`)

Comment: Thanks, John was right, and so did you. I should put divs initially hidden and not using jquery for it.